# Is it possible to call a class from inside another class (without extending)?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on different components for a basic game.

Right now my structure is I have a file of race classes that get exported to another file where I have a class that extends off of the Human race and makes a Player. Giving the Player both the attributes of a Human and a Player.

However, this means that if I wanted to make a Player that wasn't Human I would have to make a new class of Player that extends off of a different race. That seems like poor practice and I want to find a way to refactor it all to make it flow better.

---

Here is my Human class:

```
export class Human {
constructor() {
    this.type = 'Human';
    this.health = 10;
    this.baseAttack = 2;
    this.baseDefense = 1;
}
```

And here is my player Player class:

```
export class Player extends Human {
constructor(name, level){
    super();
    var inventory = {};
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.currentCapacity = 0;
    this.maxCapacity = 50;
}
```

There's other functions in the Player class related to the inventory however those don't seem relevant to my problem.

---

My intended results are that I have a group of races that when I make a Player or a Character I can select from that group and then that Player or Character will inherit attributes that are static to that race (E.g. health, baseAttack, and baseDefense).

Comment: Maybe it should be the other way around `Human extends Player`.

Comment: One option would be to forget the `class` syntax and utilize JavaScript the way it was designed. Dynamically assign a `prototype` that reflects the "race" of the "Player" using standard constructor functions and assign prototypes to them.

Comment: @PaulRooney is right. If `Player` needs to inherit from a lot of "races", maybe its the "races" that need to inherit from `Player`. One child can't have a lot of mothers, but one mother can have a lot of children.

Comment: @YongQuan I think I agree with that as well. I built the Player class first and then the Human class, and because of that I structured it the way it is. However It does make more sense to have a Player class then off of that decide the Race. However then I get worried about how I'd handle a Player, Enemies and Allies also having access to those races.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Do you mind further explaining this? I'm new to JavaScript and using this game as a way to practice and expand my knowledge.

Comment: On a side note... shouldn't it be "Species", not "Race" ? =)

Comment: @MarsAndBack I’m going off of standard rpg systems. When you make a character in Skyrim you choose a race. I guess I don’t see the reasoning behind making it “Species”

Comment: @mdkincaid Seems logical for `Enemies` and `Allies` to extend `Player`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the smart kids say, prefer composition to inheritance.  You could do something like this without deviating too far from your current approach:

```
class Orc {
  constructor() {
    this.mortal = true
  }
}

class Player {
constructor(race, name, level){
    var inventory = {};
    this.race = race;
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.currentCapacity = 0;
    this.maxCapacity = 50;
    }
}

const orc = new Player(new Orc(), 'Baz', 1 )
console.log(orc.race)
```

There are a lot of other ways to skin this cat, including having Human descend from Player. In fact, that would be the usual way to model those entities using classical inheritance (Player is general case and Humans and Orcs are more specific).

```
class PlayerClassic {
constructor(name, level){
    var inventory = {};
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.currentCapacity = 0;
    this.maxCapacity = 50;
    }
}


class Human extends PlayerClassic {
  constructor(name, level) {
    super(name, level)
    this.mortal = true
  }
}

const human = new Human('Johnny', 2)
console.log(human)
```

I find inheritance hierarchies seldom buy much advantage.  And in both of the above cases you have to use typeof to determine what sort of creature you're dealing with.

If it was my code, I'd probably skip the classes entirely.  I might do something like the following to build up a data structure that represented a constructed player:

```
const raceTemplates = {
  human: {mortal:true}, 
  elf: { mortal:true}}

const playerMaker = template => (race, name, level)=> {
  return {
    name,
    level,
    race,
    inventory: {},
    currentCapacity:0,
    maxCapacity:50,
    ...template[race]
  }
}  

const player = playerMaker(raceTemplates)('elf', 'sammy', 2)
console.log(player)
```

Here's a link to a repl.it for anyone who is interested:

https://repl.it/@rmoskal/RealisticWholeParameter

Comment: I like this idea as well. So then I'd have the race classes and the player class separate (not extending off each other) and then call the race class when I instantiate the player class.

Comment: I prefer composition that looks like this: `export const Player = Base => class extends Base { ... }` and `const OrcPlayer = Player(Orc); new OrcPlayer(...)`

Comment: I have another question, so I’ve set it up as you have suggested but when I go to display the player information, the race is displaying as an empty object and doesn’t contain the values set in the  race class. Is there some step I’m missing?

Comment: @RobertMoskal thanks! With your help I was able to fix it on my side. I realized I have to call the race attribute with the “this” keyword instead of setting them to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title:

> Can a class contain another class?

Yes, it can.

Otherwise, for your scenarios, I see `race` as an attribute (similarly player can have qualities too, that may require setting). Therefore I would suggest injecting values through a factory method. Just a simple highlight provided, but you can work a more structured `factory method` on your own.

```
function raceFactory(raceName) {
    if (raceName == 'raceA') {
        let res = new Human();
        res.health = 30;
        return res;
    }
}
```

and in the main app:

```
let humanRaceA = new factory.RaceFactory('raceA');
```

Comment: Hm, I like this option as well. I’m unfamiliar with factory function though, definitely seems to be something I’ll want to study up on. It appears to be almost like a switch with cases but more in-depth

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution

```
function Player(name, level){
    var inventory = {};
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.currentCapacity = 0;
    this.maxCapacity = 50;
}

module.exports.Player = function(race, name, level){
  var newPlayer = Object.create(Object.assign(race.prototype, Player.prototype))//override  
  race.call(newPlayer);
  Player.call(newPlayer, name, level);
  return newPlayer;
}
```

And in client code you can do something like:

```
var { Player } = require(/* your module */)
var newPlayer = Player(Human, 'Bob', 23);
console.log(newPlayer);
/*
{ type: 'Human',
  health: 10,
  baseAttack: 2,
  baseDefense: 1,
  name: 'Bob',
  level: 23,
  inventory: {},
  currentCapacity: 0,
  maxCapacity: 50 }
*/
```